# Get PID for GNU Plot Process

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a script that generates a plot string and then plots with gnuplot. I want to track the PID of the windows so I can refresh the plotted information when I replot a column.

```
$ /usr/people/shared/bin/gnuplot -p -e "${plot_string}" & 
$ PID[$plot_col]=$!
```

`plot_string` is something like `plot file.dat u 1:2 w l t 'file.dat column 2'`

What I get for the PID is something like `10880` but when I look in top I see that the actual process that is running is `10886` which is off by six.

Why are these PIDs different? How can I reliably get the only for the window?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `gnuplot` spawns the plotting window as separate process. When you call `gnuplot -p`, the plotting process is that what remains, and this has a different PID than `gnuplot` process itself.

Comment: Interesting. It's there a way to reliably get that id? Currently I just add six to the other one but that just feels like a bad idea. Is there some other way to get the id that ends up corresponding to the window?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway: what do you do with those ids? If I'm not mistaking you cannot refresh or reuse those windows anyway.

Comment: I simulate it by closing the window and re open a new one with a new plot.

Comment: Which OS and which gnuplot terminal are you using? If you use X, then you can use the gnuplot variable `GPVAL_TERM_WINDOWID` to get the window ID, and then you can use something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window) to get the PID....

Comment: I ended up just doing this `proc_list=($(ps aux | grep gnuplot | grep "pcol=$1" | grep "$2")); echo ${proc_list[1]}`. pcol is a variable that I set in the plot command that makes it unique so I just looked for that in the running gnuplot processes and it found it.

Comment: You could also start the gnuplot terminal driver yourself and get its PID that way. For example, after `gnuplot -p -e "set term xlib; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot_x11 -persist -noevents &` the shell variable `$!` will contain the PID of `gnuplot_x11` (which you might have to add to your `PATH`).

Answer (score 0):

By your command `$!` you obtain `gnuplot` PID. You can get all process child PIDs (in this case windows) by calling `pgrep -P <parent PID>`.